# ruby: object not cleaned by GC when it creates a thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, memory, garbage-collection

### Class owning a thread doesn't get garbage collected

I have a ruby service that needs to stream an object from S3 to somewhere else, the files get large and I don't want to store them as a file, so I wrote a simple class to buffer parts of the object for it to be used as an IO object by other parts of the code.

Essentially it looks like this, and full code avail in Gist linked below:

```
class S3ObjectStream
  attr_reader :s3_client, :object, :size

  def initialize(bucket, key, part_size: 5 * 1024 * 1024, num_threads: 5)
    @s3_client     = Aws::S3::Client.new(...)
    @object        = Aws::S3::Object.new(bucket_name: bucket, key:, client: @s3_client)
    @io = StringIO.new
    @size = @object.content_length
    initialize_parts
    start_parts
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self,
                                 self.class.method(:finalize).to_proc)
  end

  def self.finalize(id)
    puts "S3ObjectStream #{id} dying"
  end

  def read(size, out_buf=nil)
    # Simplified, checks if more mem needed from parts
    get_mem if need_more
    @io.read(size, out_buf)
  end

  def need_more
    #check byte ranges
  end

  def get_mem
    # Simplified...
    part = @parts.shift
    @io.rewind
    @io << part.data
    start_next_part
  end

  def initialize_parts
    @parts = []
    # Determine # of parts required
    # Create instances of them
    nparts.each do
     part = DataPart.new(...)
     @parts.push_back(part)
    end
  end

  def start_parts
     # Start downloading parts concurrently by num of threads or total parts
    # These vars are set in initialize_parts, not shown in simplified code
    num_to_start = [@num_parts, @num_threads].min
    @parts.each_with_index do |part, i|
      break if i == num_to_start

      part.start
    end
  end

  def start_next_part
    @parts.each do |part|
      next if part.started?

      part.start
      break
    end
  end
end

class DataPart
  def initialize(s3_object, start_byte, end_byte)
    @s3_object  = s3_object
    @start_byte = start_byte
    @end_byte   = end_byte
    @range      = "bytes=#{@start_byte}-#{@end_byte}"
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self,
                                 self.class.method(:finalize).to_proc)
  end

  def self.finalize(id)
    puts "DataPart #{id} dying"
  end

  def start
    @thread = Thread.new do
      @part_data = @s3_object.get(range: @range).body.read
      nil # Don't want the thread to hold onto the string as Thread.value
    end
  end

  def data
    @thread.join
    @part_data
  end
end
```

The issue we're running into is the DataPart objects don't seem to be cleaned up by the garbage collection.
My understanding is once the DataPart goes out of scope in `get_mem` (shifted off the array, then leaves scope of the method), it should be unreachable and marked for cleaning.

Initially we were running into memory issues (graphs below) where the whole file was being held in memory. Adding the `nil` to the `DataPart` thread in `start` reduced the memory usage, but we were still seeing the objects stay around forever.

Here is a graph of the memory usage of this script
[image: memory usage with threads]

Adding destructor prints to the objects showed all the `DataPart` objects that were created weren't destroyed until the program exited even when the `S3ObjectStream`s that owned those objects and the arrays of them were being destroyed as expected.

[gist showing test code and logs of objects being destroyed](https://gist.github.com/Jiig/43da21cd3e56f345d1c1d37753de8eac)

When we remove the thread from `start` and do the part downloading in serial, the `DataPart` objects get destroyed as expected during runtime GC runs. But this obviously adds a ton of time to the whole process.

Graph of the memory usage after removing the thread
[image: memory usage w/o threads]

My question is, what would cause these `DataPart`s to stick around with the inclusion of a thread? Is there a circular dependency here that I'm not understanding between the thread objects and the owning `DataPart`s?

Comment: how do you know it gets/does not get destroyed? where do you see memory issues?
do you measure memory usage of ruby from OS level?

Comment: Yes I monitored memory usage from the OS, in the long running service the memory would bloat to the same size as the input file, and if run multiple times would bloat to whatever the file size was * the amount of times run.

Once we had the Thread in `DataPart.start` return nil, the memory usage capped at a reasonable limit. But using a non threaded approach the overall memory usage was even lower.

As for knowing things were destroyed: I added finalizers to `S3ObjectStream` and `DataPart`. Adding a gist and some images to the main post

Comment: So after an initial increase of memory the level stays the same => there is no leak, this is just the amount of memory that Ruby requested from OS and NEVER RETURNED....
Have a look at  https://www.speedshop.co/2017/12/04/malloc-doubles-ruby-memory.html

try using

jemalloc or set MALLOC_ARENA_MAX if you can not change the allocator. Or if neither is possible try working with smaller chunks of data which might help. But only if the target where you write the data to does not accumulate everything in memory.

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining this well. I think I might repost or re-edit this question with a simpler example that really shows the question I have.

Comment: Did you add a new question? 
Just be aware: ruby does not return memory back to the OS, so once  it has been allocated to ruby, it is gone for the OS. This means:

* if your memory usage flattens out, you probably do not have a leak (you might be wasteful with memory though)
* Your minimum memory requirement for ruby is the max amount of data that you hold at the same time within your objects (plus overhead)
* GC does not release memory to OS, it just makes it available within Ruby

Answer (score 0):

Rather than some objects not being garbage collected, I'd rather assume that your `StringIO` object in `@io` just gets larger on each read, since you append the data there in `S3ObjectStream#get_mem`.

As `StringIO` is basically just a normal String with a different interface to work like an `IO` object, what happens here is that you are just increasing the size of the underlying string, without ever releasing the read data again. Please be aware that with a `StringIO` object, just reading data from it will not delete previously read data from the String; you can always call `rewind` on it to read everything from the beginning again.

To avoid this, you should probably try to get rid of the `@io` object altogether and just use a simple String object. In `get_mem`, you can then append data to this string. In `read`, you can use [`String#byteslice`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/String.html#method-i-bytesplice) to get up to `size` bytes of data *and* remove this read data from the buffer. That way, your buffer will not grow unbounded.

This can look like this:

```
class S3ObjectStream
  def initialize(bucket, key, part_size: 5 * 1024 * 1024, num_threads: 5)
    # ...

    # a mutable string in binary encoding
    @buffer = +"".force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)
  end

  def get_mem
    part = @parts.shift
    @buffer << part.data
  end

  def read(size, out_buf = nil)
    # Simplified, checks if more mem needed from parts
    get_mem if need_more

    data = @buffer.byteslice(0, size)
    if out_buf
       out_buf.replace data
       out_buf
    else
       data
    end
  end
end
```

The `out_buf` is more or less useless in this implementation though and probably doesn't help in nay way. But likely, it doesn't hurt either.

Note that neither this construct nor your previous `StringIO` object is thread-safe. If you are thus appending to and/or reading from the `@buffer` from multiple concurrent threads, you need to add appropriate mutexes.

In addition to the `@io` issue, it also appears from tyour simplified code, that you are starting to get all parts in parallel, each in its own thread. Thus, each `DataPart` object hold its read data in memory in the `@part_data` variable. As you initialize all DataPart objects for your data in parallel at the start, your memory will grow to contain all parts anyway. The cobstructiuon wiuth partially getting a data part from the `@parts` array and appending its data to a buffer is thus rather pointless.

Instead, you probably have to only get a few DataParts (or one at a time) as they are consumed and continue creating/fetching additional DataParts as you read the data.

Comment: I didn't realize I had omitted the rewind call from my example, it is being called. We are also only doing a handful of parts at a time, ill edit the main post to make that more clear.